# Apache Airflow. Передача параметров из plugin view в DAG

Tags: python-3.x, apache

Есть следующая задача. в проекте с Apache Airflow нужно создать плагин тоесть кастомную страницу на которой будет форма с параметрами и кнопка, которая запустит DAG с введенными в форму параметрами.

**plugin.py**

```
from airflow.plugins_manager import AirflowPlugin
from flask_admin import BaseView, expose
from flask_appbuilder import BaseView as AppBuilderBaseView


class TestViews(AppBuilderBaseView):
    template_folder = '/usr/local/airflow/plugins/templates'

    @expose("/")
    def list(self):
        return self.render_template("test.html",    content="Hello Test!")

    @expose("/run")
    def run(self):
        return self.render_template("test.html", content="Hello Test!")


test_view = TestViews()
test_package = {"name": "Test", "category": "Test Category", "view": test_view}


class TestPlugin(AirflowPlugin):
    name = 'testing'
    appbuilder_views = [test_package]
```

**testing_dag.py**

```
from datetime import datetime
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator


dag = DAG(
    'testing',
    start_date=datetime(2020, 9, 30),
    schedule_interval='15 0 * * 1',
    catchup=False
)


def _testing(ds, **kwargs):
    print(kwargs)


testing_operator = PythonOperator(
    task_id='testing_op',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=_testing,
    dag=dag
)
```

Можно ли такое сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Вообщем замутил вот такую штуку. И вроде работает как надо.

**in plugin.py**

```
@expose("/run")
def run(self):
    req = requests.post(
        url='http://localhost:8080/api/experimental/dags/testing/dag_runs',
        headers={'Cache-Control': 'no-cache', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        json={'conf': {'got': 'it!!!'}}
    )
    return self.render_template("test.html", content="Hello Test!")
```

**in testing_dag.py**

```
def _testing(ds, **kwargs):
    dag_run = DagRun.find(run_id=kwargs.get('run_id'))[0]
    print(dag_run)
    print(dag_run.conf) # {'got': 'it!!!'}
```